# How to use 3 different datatables under 3 different view models in same view?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, datatable

I have a view page that has 3 radio buttons. I have 3 data tables and 3 view models. When I click search, I want only one data table to display and show data - that was chosen by radio button.

If I choose radio button 'B', after I click search, my 2nd data table needs to be displayed, 1st and 3rd table must be hidden.

Code that I tried:

For Radio button:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4  col-lg-4">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            @Html.RadioButton("RBData", "true", new { @checked = true }) Data 1
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4  col-lg-4">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            @Html.RadioButton("RBData", "true", new { @checked = true }) Data 2
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4  col-lg-4">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            @Html.RadioButton("RBData", "true", new { @checked = true }) Data 3
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

For 3 datatable:

```
@model IEnumerable<ViewModel.DetailsVM>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 datagrid">
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" style="width:100%" id="table1" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-hd">
<thead>
    <tr class="gridheader">
        <td style="width: 25%;" >value 1</td>
        <td style="width: 25%;" >value 2</td>
        <td style="width: 25%;" >value 3</td>
        <td style="width: 25%;" >value 4</td>               
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @if (Model != null)
{
foreach (var m in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.value1)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.value2)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.value3)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.value4)</td>
        </tr>
}
}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
@model IEnumerable<ViewModel.ContactsVM>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 datagrid">
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" style="width:100%" id="table2" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-hd">
<thead>
    <tr class="gridheader">
        <td style="width: 25%;" >value 1</td>
        <td style="width: 25%;" >value 2</td>
        <td style="width: 25%;" >value 3</td>
        <td style="width: 25%;" >value 4</td>               
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @if (Model != null)
{
foreach (var m in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.value1)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.value2)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.value3)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.value4)</td>
        </tr>
}
}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
@model IEnumerable<ViewModel.DataVM>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 datagrid">
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" style="width:100%" id="table3" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-hd">
<thead>
    <tr class="gridheader">
        <td style="width: 25%;" >value 1</td>
        <td style="width: 25%;" >value 2</td>
        <td style="width: 25%;" >value 3</td>
        <td style="width: 25%;" >value 4</td>               
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @if (Model != null)
{
foreach (var m in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.value1)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.value2)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.value3)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.value4)</td>
        </tr>
}
}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

and for the search button:

```
 <div class="btn-group">
     <button id="btnSearch" type="submit" name="btnSearch" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-flat"><span class="hide-on-mobile">Search </span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
 </div>
```

I am new to MVC with different viewmodels. I got a message, that more than one viewmodel cannot be not used in same view. But how to fix this, I need to get data for the datatable from the controller after clicking search button. So far, I was familiar with single viewmodel return only. To display and hide data table, can we use javascript? How to fix this?

Comment: was your question answered

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to fix this,

option 1. separate your 3 loops into 3 partialviews and load the one you need when you search.

option 2. Create one view model class that contains details, contacts, and data.

If `model.details.count()!=0` do your loop, etc.

more on partial views:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.0

- right click your views folder and add partial view.  Do not inherit layout.
  Your html for the table goes here.  Name it _details for example.
- create a controller action for it, it will return partial view
- when you click search you want to render the correct partial view:

  @{
      await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_details");//or contacts etc.
  }

The one large class option:

```
public class AllVMData{

public class DetailsVM{get;set;}
public class DataVM{get;set;}
public class ContactsVM{get;set;}
}
```

And then on the razor stuff check for `Model.DetailsVM` is null, etc before doing that loop.